# Random query from Firebase Realtime Database with specific userid(Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database

I need to choice some random queries which added by users to Firebase database. Any way to do that?

To be more specific, I have queries like below and wanted to get random imDBid from belong to logged user, so is there any way such as; firstly filter list by userid then getting a random data from that?

```
movielist
         movies
              -M5RwyBsC1cwTzX4LU-A
                 backdropPath: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/5BwqwxMEjeF..."
                 genres: "Science Fiction, Drama"
                 imDBid: "tt2935510"
                 posterPath: "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/original/xBHvZcjRiWy..."
                 releaseDate: "2019"
                 title: "Ad Astra"
                 userId: "SZ7zU6toVcSSablbnZif8n4MTIb2"
                 voteAverage: "6.6"
                 unique: "SZ7zU6toVcSSablbnZif8n4MTIb2tt2935510"
                 watched: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved that below method, writing here if anyone needs similar solution;

```
List movietemp = [];
var db = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("movies").orderByChild("userId").equalTo(userId);
           db.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot){
           Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
           values.forEach((key,values) {
             movietemp.add(values["imDBid"]);});

           Random random = new Random();
           int randomNumber = random.nextInt(movietemp.length);

           _name = movietemp[randomNumber]
       }
    );
```